# split but not the string under string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string - `"hi#i#am#hum'#'an ";`

I want to split the string for an operator `#`, but don't want to split the string which is under single quote.

So I want the result - `["hi","i","am","hum#an"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution, not a one liner though. First replace `'#'` with some temporary character. Then apply the split, and replace temp character with `#`.

```js
var str = "hi#i#am#hum'#'an";
str = str.replace(/'#'/g, '&');
str = str.split('#');
str = str.map(s => s.replace(/&/g, '#'))
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
input.split( /#(?!')/ )
```

**Demo**

```js
var output = "hi#i#am#hum'#'an ".split( /#(?!')/ ).map( s => s.replace(/'#'/g, "#") );

console.log( output );
```